# TShellTreeView memory leak

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe8

I'm using MadExcept to trace memory leaks. If I put a TShellTreeView on a form and run the application MadExcept reports a memory leak. Just opening and closing, nothing else. I am using the XE6 package under XE8, since this is the last one released AFAIK.

I know there were some problems with former delphi versions, but these are fixed in the XE6 package, I think.

This is the MadExcept Window shown after app shutdown:

[image: MadExcept ScreenShot]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, madExcept is correct which is to be expected because it is of exceptionally high quality. This is indeed a defect in the code you use. It looks like this:

```
function CreateRootFolder(RootFolder: TShellFolder; OldRoot : TRoot;
  var NewRoot: TRoot): TShellFolder;
var
  P: PWideChar;
  NewPIDL: PItemIDList;
  NumChars,
  Flags,
  HR: LongWord;
  ErrorMsg : string;
begin
  HR := S_FALSE;
  if GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TRootFolder), NewRoot) >= 0 then
  begin
    HR := SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(
            0,
            nFolder[GetCSIDLType(NewRoot)],
            NewPIDL);
  end
  else if Length(NewRoot) > 0 then
  begin
    if NewRoot[Length(NewRoot)] = ':' then NewRoot := NewRoot + '\';
    NumChars := Length(NewRoot);
    Flags := 0;
    P := StringToOleStr(NewRoot);
    HR := DesktopShellFolder.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, P, NumChars, NewPIDL, Flags);
  end;

  if HR <> S_OK then
  begin
    { TODO : Remove the next line? }
    // Result := RootFolder;
    ErrorMsg := Format( SErrorSettingPath, [ NewRoot ] );
    NewRoot := OldRoot;
    raise Exception.Create( ErrorMsg );
  end;

  Result := CreateRootFromPIDL(NewPIDL);
  if Assigned(RootFolder) then RootFolder.Free;
end;
```

In both branches, it is the responsibility of the caller to destroy `NewPIDL`. The code does not do so. That this is so can be discerned by reading the documentation:

- [`SHGetSpecialFolderLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762203.aspx).
- [`IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775090.aspx).

Amend the final part of the function to be like so:

```
Result := CreateRootFromPIDL(NewPIDL);
if Assigned(RootFolder) then RootFolder.Free;
CoTaskMemFree(NewPIDL);
```

I can confirm that I have tested this change. I tested the original code and reproduced the leak that you reported. I then changed the code as described above and madExcept reports no leak.

That you have been unable to achieve the same means that you are not executing the modified code. Perhaps you are using runtime packages and have not recompiled the modified code. Or perhaps there is another explanation. Anyway, it is completely clear to me that your failure to remove the leak is because you are still running the original unmodified code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copied+pasted your suggestion to the CreateRootFolder function in the ShellCtrls, but I still get the same message on shutdown..Did I miss something here?

Comment: @Ida: There's more to it than just copying and pasting the first block. Read the entire answer, **particularly the part below the two links** (at the bottom).

Comment: I'm confident that if you free the PIDL, the code won't leak

Comment: @David: So my changes are according to your suggestion? If yes, the code is still leaking..

Comment: You added the call to CoTaskMemFree? Do you understand why it's needed and what it does?

Comment: Yes, I added it. the NewPIDL is created in this line  Result := CreateRootFromPIDL(NewPIDL);  And its supposed to be freed in this line:  CoTaskMemFree(NewPIDL);

Comment: No. CreateRootFromPIDL does not create the PIDL. It use it.

Comment: Ok, you are right..It's created further above..Maybe it is getting too late for me, but I still do not get your point. I added the block to the function and it still does not work. So, is there something else to be done? if not the leak is still there..

Comment: I don't understand that. The leak report is clear. Let me check tomorrow.

Comment: It's is exactly as I described. Whatever code you changed, you aren't running it. You are still running the original code. When I make the change, the leak disappears. I think this question is well and truly done.

Comment: @Ida You seem to have gone quiet. What's up?

Comment: I double checked, if I am using still the old code: I did the changes in the ShellCtrls.pas, recompiled and installed the shell controls to my IDE again. I really do not want to bother you, but MadExcept is still complaining. I even tried it on another machine using XE2.  What OS do you use? I used Windows 10 on both machines.

Comment: I've no idea what you are doing. I took the source code and compiled it directly into my executable by adding it to me project. Then madExcept stopped reporting the leak. I have answered the question you asked, and now you are stuck on a completely different problem. Namely that of trying to link the right code.

Comment: @David: I added the unit to my project, now it works. Thanks!  Do you have an explanation why it is not working the way I tried it?

Comment: Because whatever you were linking to wasn't the modified code.